# c# List<Items> with DateTime get all from last 6 weeks

Tags: c#

I have a List and Item contains a DateTime property. The list is populated with a lot of data.

I need to get the last 6 weeks items from today.

I'm thinking to do it like this:

6 weeks = 6 weeks x 7 days = 42 days

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

DateTime startDate = today.AddDays(42);

List<Item> list = list.Where(t=>t.Created.Date >= startDate.Date && t.Created.date <= today.Date)
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same?

Comment: Looks good to me. But you need `ToList` call to make it compiler.

Comment: Your code looks fine in principle, but shouldn't it be `startDate = today.AddDays( -42 )`, otherwise you're getting events from the future.

Comment: No, I think that is fine, but I think where you calculate the startDate you are going in the wrong direction (into the future).

Comment: I'd also write `-6 * 7` instead of `-42`, to make the meaning clear. Also, you can write `DateTime.Today` so you can drop that `.Date` in the `Where`

Comment: true that should be - 42 and .ToList()

Comment: Before you clarify what "better" means for you this question is likely "opinion based"... Please consider clarifying what kind of improvement to algorithm you hope to find OR possibly move question to codereview site.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `TimeSpan` and `DateTime.Subtract` to achieve the same thing in an (arguably) more idiomatic form.

```
var sixWeeks = TimeSpan.FromDays(42);
var list = source.Where(t=>t.Created.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date.Subtract(sixWeeks));
```